# node express api versioning throws 404 route

Tags: node.js, express

#### app/routes/v1/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const test = require('./test');
router.use('/test', test);

module.exports = router;
```

#### server.js

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();
const v1 = require('./app/routes/v1');

app.use('/api', v1);
```

## test.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("test");
});

module.exports = router;
```

#### App started:

```
Express app started on port 3000
GET /api/test 404 143.858 ms - -
```

I keep getting 404 when I hit from postman `http://localhost:3000/api/test`

Comment: your code looks fine at first glance. need more information to help you further, For example, it's important to verify that the server is actually running.

Comment: What is `test` from `require('./test')`?

Comment: can you share your `test.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current your code, the correct path will be `/api/test/test`. Every time you use syntax `app.use('/something, require('module'))` that mean you add prefix path `/something` in group route in `module`.

You should use prefix path `/` in module controller `test.js`:

```
// test.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
// full path: /api/v1/test
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("test");
});

// full path: /api/v1/
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("something");
});

module.exports = router;
```